# Rails: Uninitialized constant User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

Background - I am working with rails version 5.1.2. I am using Cloud 9 IDE. My problem relates to Ch 11 Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.
Problem details - typing $  rails test:mailers:

---

Error:
UserMailerTest#test_account_activation:
NameError: uninitialized constant User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
    app/models/user.rb:6:in `<class:User>'
    app/models/user.rb:1:in`'

bin/rails test test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:5

---

app/models/user.rb:1     -    app/models/user.rb:6:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Where are you defining? VALID_EMAIL_REGEX

Comment: Thank you for your response.  A solution was found by following your guidance below. I modified app/model/user.rb to include:
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
       .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the regex in your User model

```
class User < ApplicationsRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 ...

end
```

Comment: These days you really need to be way more generous: `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+/z` is the closest we can get. [Email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) can and will contain all sorts of crazy stuff including non-ASCII characters and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Antarr Byrd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560409/10907864).

I had a similar experience when working on a Rails Application.

The issue was that I was defining the REGEX constant below the point of validation call.

**That is, instead of this**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
end
```

**Do this rather**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**